# Obtaining localized strings for a particular language

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, localization

I am trying to obtain localized strings for the English language (in en.lproj/Localizable.strings) for use as default values when the localized string for the user's preferred language is not found.

I want to pass in that default value to this method:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:defaultValue table:nil]
```

But I haven't found an easy way to obtain that value. 
I can create a dictionary from the strings file but I was wondering if there is a more convenient way?

Answer (score 1):

I think it Cocoa uses the english strings as fallbacks automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Is English your development region (language)? If so, by default any localisable string that hasn’t been translated to the user’s preferred language will fallback to English. This is governed by the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in your application plist. From the [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html),

> **CFBundleDevelopmentRegion**
>
> CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (String - iOS, Mac OS X) specifies the native region for the bundle. This key contains a string value that usually corresponds to the native language of the person who wrote the bundle. The language specified by this value is used as the default language if a resource cannot be located for the user’s preferred region or language.

This key is automatically added to the Info.plist file create by Xcode’s templates. Its ‘friendly’ representation is *Localization native development region.*